# поиск в массиве angular

Tags: angular2, typescript

Есть класс с пользователями и pipe который ищет в нем элементы, но один из объектов класса стал массивом и поиск сломался помогите починить.

Поиск:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'FilterPipe',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, input: string) {
    if (input) {
      input = input.toLowerCase();
      return value.filter(function (el: any) {
        if (el.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
          return el.phone.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        }
        if (el.mobile.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
          return el.mobile.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        }
        if (el.dep.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
          return el.dep.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        }
        if (el.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
          return el.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        }
        if (el.owner.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
          return el.owner.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
        }
      })
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Класс в котором ищем:

```
export class Member {
  id: number;
  phone: string;
  mobile: string[];
  dep: string;
  email: string;
  owner: string;
}
```

Когда mobile: string - был не массивом все работало, но нужно иметь несколько номеров и поиск отказывается так искать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решается заменой поиска для mobile на:

```
if (el.mobile.some(elem => elem.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1)) {
  return el;
}
```

Comment: Если это верное решенние, поставте галочку, т.е. примите ответ..

Comment: Да, так и поступлю, но смогу сделать это только через 4 часа)